# Bootstrap Datetime Picker not working with Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, bootstrap-4

We are using [Eonasdan](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) Datetime picker. We are migrated to Boostrap 4 Alpha 6 since it comes with lot of improvements over Alpha5 but Datetime picker broken. Now it's not showing the numbers when we click on calendar icon in datetime picker.But it's working with [alpha 5](https://plnkr.co/edit/FszymR?p=preview).I am looking for a possible way to solve this.

```js
// Code goes here

$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Bootstrap date time picker</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container" style="margin:50px;">
      <h4>Bootstrap Datetime Picker</h4>
      <div class="row">
          <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                          <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
         
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.2/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap Datepicker is not yet compatible with Bootstrap 4, and *as you know, the developer is already aware* of this issue: http://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1996

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Classes `collapse in` classes were changed into `collapse show`, that's why the code became incompatible.

in your **vendor\eonasdan\bootstrap-datetimepicker\src\js\bootstrap-datetimepicker.js**

getTemplate:

```
if (hasDate()) {
 content.append($('<li>').addClass((options.collapse && hasTime() ? 'collapse in' : '')).append(dateView));
```

Change to:

```
if (hasDate()) {
  content.append($('<li>').addClass((options.collapse && hasTime() ? 'collapse show' : '')).append(dateView));
  }
```

togglePicker:

```
   expanded = $parent.find('.in'),
  closed = $parent.find('.collapse:not(.in)'),
```

and

```
   } else { // otherwise just toggle in class on the two views
     expanded.removeClass('in');
     closed.addClass('in');
```

Change to:

```
 expanded = $parent.find('.show'),
 closed = $parent.find('.collapse:not(.show)'),
```

and

```
  } else { // otherwise just toggle in class on the two views
  expanded.removeClass('show');
 closed.addClass('show');
```

[Source](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1996)

Comment: I've applied your changes, but it still doesn't work. the plugin is properly initialized, no errors there. and the input value gets populated correctly. but when i open the picker, the UI is messed up. i can hover over the content area to find the buttons for setting a time value. but the datepicker UI is all gone. this is becoming tedious, ive been trying to find a datetime picker for bootstrap 4. ive been migrating to bootstrap 4 beta and a datetime picker component is essential. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For display correctly all icons in eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker you can add only the glyphicons to your page using this tag:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bower_components/glyphicons-only-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' />
```

or install it with:

```
// using npm
npm install glyphicons-only-bootstrap

// using bower
bower install glyphicons-only-bootstrap
```

This help you to show correctly all icons in the component, for correctly display component follow the steps mentioned above for Heretron and sr9yar.

Obviously you also can copy the fonts from dist folder in boostrap 3 and the css relative to it, but the previously option is generally more fast.

This is the repository in github of glyphicon-only-bootstrap:

https://github.com/ohpyupi/glyphicons-only-bootstrap

Good luck, I hope have help you

PD: Sorry if my english is wrong. Bye